# Sql Server delete syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete

I recently faced a delete syntax I was unaware of.

```
delete #fooTbl from #fooTbl where attr ='some'
```

The Official Microsoft documentation states:

```
DELETE FROM [database_name . [ schema ] . | schema. ] table_name    
[ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
[ OPTION ( <query_options> [ ,...n ]  ) ]
[; ]
```

i have some perplexity about the command I wrote:

- What is and what is needed that parameter before the delete keyword (In my example coincides with table name)?
- What is the best practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is and what is needed that parameter before the delete keyword
>   (In my example coincides with table name)?

Referencing the table is a possibility due to the fact that you could `DELETE FROM` with an `INNER JOIN`.

**A simple example of deleting from `#footbl` with an `inner join` to a different table**

```
DELETE FT
FROM 
#DifferentTable DT
INNER JOIN #fooTbl FT
ON DT.attr = FT.attr
WHERE FT.attr ='some';
```

**Whereas this generates an error due to not specifying what table to delete from**

```
DELETE  
FROM #DifferentTable AS  DT
INNER JOIN #fooTbl AS FT
ON DT.attr = FT.attr
WHERE FT.attr ='some';
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 45 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AS'.

**And this also works**

```
DELETE  #fooTbl
FROM #DifferentTable AS  DT
INNER JOIN #fooTbl AS FT
ON DT.attr = FT.attr
WHERE FT.attr ='some';
```

In short, you need to specify the alias/table to delete from if you are referencing multiple tables, but you don't have to when you only reference the one.

> What is the best practice?

In terms of best practice I don't think that it matters much for the single table. Aliasses can be useful as to make adapting / reusing scripts easier.

---

**Some more examples in the Microsoft documentation**

[D. Using joins and subqueries to data in one table to delete rows in another table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-using-joins-and-subqueries-to-data-in-one-table-to-delete-rows-in-another-table)

**Using the table name twice**

```
DELETE FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory   
FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh  
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp  
ON spqh.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
```

**Using an alias**

```
DELETE spqh  
  FROM  
        Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh  
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp  
        ON spqh.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID  
  WHERE  sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
```

Both serving the exact same purpose.